# encoding U00d8\U00aa\ NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, mobile, nsstring

I'm receiving remote notification with string

**\U00d8\U00aa\U00d8\U00aa\U00d8\U00a7\U00d8\U00a7"**
 I would like to display this string in alert dialog.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Alert"
                                                    message:/*alertValue*/decodedString
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
```

but it oesn't shown correctly, what i need to do to encode it correctly?

Comment: What is the problem, and what does it show as?

Comment: currently it shows strange characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out:

```
NSString *decodedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[alertValue cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]];
```